# Return-to-libc attack with the argument read from registers (EDI/RDI)

Tags: linux, exploit, buffer-overflow

I've read that to make a successful return-to-libc attack, the attacker should store the address of the command (for example `/bin/sh`) in the stack exactly after the return address of the `system` function (for example). This way the `system()` function reads that address as its parameter and executes that command. But now after disassembling a program which calls `system()` I noticed that it doesn't use the stack to get the address of that string (`"/bin/sh"`). Instead the address is stored in the EDI or RDI registers. As long as the attacker can't access the registers how is it possible to perform such attack?

Here is a simple example:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    system("id");
    return 0;
}
```

And the disassembled one:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp
mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
mov    $0x4005dc,%edi     #Here the address of string is copied to EDI
callq  0x4003e0 <system@plt>
mov    $0x0,%eax
leaveq 
retq
```

Comment: You're probably running into [a linker optimisation](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/what-x86-calling-convention-passes-first-parameter-via-esi).

Comment: At first I run the program under linux. but that thread is talking about MSDN as microsoft. second in the situation I explained situation is it possible to perform return-to-lib-c attack or not?

Comment: The linker optimisation mentioned there isn't exclusive to Microsoft toolchains. Actually - can you post the disassembly that you've seen? It may be a direct syscall rather than an actual call to `system()`.

Comment: @Polynomial I updated the question with the codes. Please review

Comment: Ah, it's a [PLT](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-is-plt-got).

Comment: @Polynomial well I will study about it later. But in THIS situation is return-to-lib-c possible? It doesn't seem so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is a PLT, which is a way of doing late-bound library imports. The "calling convention" of PLTs isn't standard, but the toolchain usually uses register-based parameter passing for performance, which is why you're seeing `edi` as the address of the string. The call will go to a stub in the Global Offset Table (GOT) which then calls into the library function.

The answer is **yes**, you can exploit this with a ret2libc, but not a standard one. You'll need to use a ret-to-plt technique instead, which is described [in this paper](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/17286.pdf) (PDF). The point is that you use ROP gadgets to massage the registers into containing the right values, which can then call into the PLT.

Comment: Thank You. Apparently it's more complicated than it seemed at beginning.